# EPPLUS - Rename Cell

Tags: excel, epplus

I'm using EPPLUS to build custom Excel spread sheets.  One functionality that I'm missing is to change the name of a cell.  Is this somehow possible with EPPLUS?  If not are there any other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that `book` is your workbook and `sheet` is your worksheet. Let try this code snippet

```
var cell = sheet.Cells["C2"]; // Cell or Range you want to name
sheet.Names.Add("The_Name_Here", cell);
```

The name will be added to sheet. If you want to access the name in the whole workbook, try:

```
var cell = sheet.Cells["C2"]; // Cell or Range you want to name
book.Names.Add("The_Name_Here", cell);
```

Depend on your need the scope of the name can be `sheet.Names` or `book.Names`.
I don't know how to modify an existing name but sure that 1 cell/range may have multiple names.