# EPPLUS - Get Name Of Cell//Range

Tags: epplus

I know it is possible to give a cell a name, as answered in the following question:

[EPPLUS - Rename Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724482/epplus-rename-cell/13764571?iemail=1#13764571)

How can you see if a given cell/range has a name and retrieve that name?

Answer (score 2):

There is a property i.e. `IsName` that can determine the range has a name or not. But it seems not to work properly. I suppose you to query the named cells collection i.e. `sheet.Names` or `book.Names` (they contains all the names in the sheet or the book). Then compare `FullAddressAbsolute` to the given cell to get the named cell you want.

```
var cell = sheet.Cells["C1"]; // cell you wanna find the name
ExcelNamedRange namedCell = null;
foreach (var item in book.Names)
{
    if (item.FullAddressAbsolute.Equals(cell.FullAddressAbsolute))
    {
        namedCell = item;
        break; // if you don't wanna find all
    }
}
// if (namedCell == null) --> NOT FOUND
// else
//      namedCell.Name : contains the name you wanna retrieve
```

LINQ can also be used instead of the loop:

```
namedCell = book.Names.Where(item => item.FullAddressAbsolute.Equals(cell.FullAddressAbsolute)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Only Workbook gives collection of Names, sheet doesn't

Comment: I don't know which version you are using. But for sure that EPPlus 3.1.2 provides both two scopes.

Comment: Sorry EPPlus was a missed part. I'm working with VSTO directly.